# Insert at any position a php object into an array of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, position

I want to insert $my_object into an array of objects, for example between the fourth and fifth element of $my_array_of_objects.

```
$my_object = myObject ();

$my_array_of_objects = Array ( 
[1] => Object ()
[2] => Object ()
[3] => Object ()
[4] => Object ()
[5] => Object ()
)

// to something like this :
$my_array_of_objects = Array ( 
[1] => Object ()
[2] => Object ()
[3] => Object ()
[4] => Object ()
[5] => myObject () //the position i want to insert my object
[6] => Object ()
)
```

I try this but it dosen't work.
`array_splice($my_array_of_objects, 0, 4, $my_object);`

I know how to add $my_object at the end of the array but not at any position.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this

```
$my_object = myObject ();

$postion = 4;

$my_array_of_objects = Array ( 
[1] => Object ()
[2] => Object ()
[3] => Object ()
[4] => Object ()
[5] => Object ()
)


$new_objects_array = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($my_array_of_objects);$i++)
{
    if($i == $postion)
    {
        array_push($new_objects_array , $my_object);
    
    }
    else
    {
    
        array_push($new_objects_array , $my_array_of_objects[$i]);
    }
    

}
```

let me know if it's working

cheers !!

Comment: array_push sorry , i fixed the answer

Comment: You should not use `array_push()`, but `$new_objects_array[] = $my_object;`, because the function has a overhead. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array, by slicing and merging.

```
$array = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

$insertPosition = 4;
$newElement= 'ABC';
$newArray = array_merge(array_slice($array, 0, $insertPosition), [$newElement], array_slice($array, $insertPosition));

print_r($newArray);
```

gives you

```
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => ABC
    [5] => 5
    [6] => 6
)
```

### Alternative

Instead of using arrays, you could use a Double Linked List. Because it implements the Iterable interface, you can also foreach over it.

```
$list = new SplDoublyLinkedList();
$list->push(1);
$list->push(2);
$list->push(3);
$list->push(4);
$list->push(5);
$list->push(6);

$list->add(4, 'ABC');
print_r($list);
```

gives

```
SplDoublyLinkedList Object
(
    [flags:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => 0
    [dllist:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => ABC
            [5] => 5
            [6] => 6
        )

)
```

Comment: I tried your first solution and it worked like a charme !! :) Thank you so much. I haven't tried your alternative yet. But maybe a little too new to PHP to fully understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Correct call with [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php#refsect1-function.array-splice-parameters) will be:

```
array_splice($my_array_of_objects, 4, 0, [$my_object]);
```

Which means:

- starting at position **4** remove **0** elements in `$my_array_of_objects`.
- replace these "deleted" elements with values from array which holds only one value - `$my_object`.